# Why is persist method called twice?

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

In my service level I create a new object from Entity1 class and persist it and then call setters on it. but after all, another object from Entity1 will be created and inserted in database( so I will have two rows in Entity1 table inserted in database instead of one). MyEntity1 has a `many-to-many` relationship with itself and I set it after calling persist method.
My problem is that I can't find why an additional Entity1 object is created in my application.

My service class:

```
MyEntity1 e1 = new MyEntity1();
em.persist(e1); 
MyEntity2 e2 = new MyEntity2();
e2.setChild(e1);
e2.setParent(e1);
e1.getParent().add(e2);
e1.getChildren().add(e2);
```

MyEntity1 class has two oneToMany relationships with itself (it is a manyToMany relation with additional column):

MyEntity1 class:

```
 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "child", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MyEntity2> parent = new ArrayList<MyEntity2>();

 @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")  
    private List<MyEntity2> children= new ArrayList<MyEntity2>();
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on the problem?  You say persist is called twice, which is something the application calls, not JPA, while in your description you state "two different object are created and stored in database.".  What two different objects are created, and how are you specifying the primary keys of the entities to differentiate them?  Which entity is the problem?

Comment: yes sure, I edited the question. an additional Entity1 object will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly (which is hard without some code), you persist an entity and after that add a relationship to another instance?

When you call `persist` on an entity, it becomes `managed entity` which means JPA provider now manages its lifecycle. That means you no longer have to call `merge` or `persist` on it in order to save changes. JPA provider does this automatically, and that's why the second entity is also persisted.

```
MyEntity e1 = new MyEntity();
em.persist(e1); // this persists the entity, and makes it managed 
MyEntity e2 = new MyEntity();
e1.setRelation(e2);
// this will also persist (if cascade is properly configured) e2 at the end of transaction, without you persisting it manually
```

Comment: I exactly do the same thing. First I call the persist and then call the setter.

Comment: Then you have the explanation (read the comments in my example).

Comment: its different from my case predrag. I added some of the code.

Comment: Actually, it's basically the same. After calling `em.persist(e1)`, entity `e1` becomes managed ([more info](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/undejbs003.htm)). After that, you add `e2` as its relation. At the end of transaction, JPA provider sees that there is a new entity in `e1`'s object graph, and persists it (that's `e2`). The result is two rows in database.

Comment: my bad explanation. two objects from Entity1 will be inserted in database.

Comment: `e1` and `e2` in my example are of the same type, it doesn't change anything. If it is still not clear to you what is happening, maybe you should write a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it in the question.